# How do I update CiviVolunteer, from the UI or from the command line?

Tags: drupal, extension, civivolunteer, upgrade

I'm running Civi 5.19.alpha1 with Drupal locally. I have CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1, which is the latest release listed on GitHub, from June 2018.

I want to update to the latest stuff in the repo, which I believe fixes a bug.

I don't see a way to do that in the Admin UI.

I've tried

`git pull https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer.git`

from my ext directory at

`~/buildkit/build/drupal-clean/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext`

and I get

`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: Oh yeah :) . So I did not have a remote. I did this: `git remote add -m -f civivolunteer https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer.git` then this - `git fetch civivolunteer` then I get this: `warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 11179 (delta 0), reused 6 (delta 0), pack-reused 11173
Receiving objects: 100% (11179/11179), 2.99 MiB | 591.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5911/5911), done.
From https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volu`... etc

Answer (score 2):

You will need to

- Go into your extension dir and remove the civivolunteer code that was
  installed with your buildkit.

  Then git clone their master (to get the latest).

  Then go to the Manage Extensions page to check if there are any
  prompts for database updates.

  Then disable a small other extension and re-enable it. Or just enable
  another new extension via the Manage Extensions page. This will
  trigger managed entity updates.

Comment: Karin thanks so much. So if the update is in a different branch then of course I should `git clone` that branch.

Comment: Right - here’s an example of how to check out a different branch from eg webform civicrm module: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/where-do-i-find-webform-civicrm-module-for-d8

Comment: Note the —branch flag

Comment: Karin, yup, thanks so much!